# DBSCAN sklearn is very slow

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to cluster a dataset has more than 1 million data points. One column has text and the other column has a numeric value corresponding to it. The problem that I am facing is that it gets stuck and never completes. I have tried to work with smaller datasets of around 100,000 and it works fairly quickly but as I start increasing data points it starts slowing down and for a million it never completes and hangs. Initially, I thought it might be because I have a tfidf matrix for text and there are 100 dimensions so it is taking a long time. Then I tried clustering based on the amount which is just a single value for each data point and it still did not complete. Below is the code snippet. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I have seen people working with larger data sets and having no problem.

```
Y=data['amount'].values
Y=Y.reshape(-1,1)
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples= 10, algorithm='kd_tree')
dbscan.fit_predict(Y)
labels = dbscan.labels_
print(labels.size)
clusters = labels.tolist()
#printing the value and its label
for a, b in zip(labels, Y):
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: How long did you actually wait for it to complete?

Comment: What do you mean by "clustering based on the amount which is just a single value for each data point"  ? Did you do hyper parameter tuning on `eps` and `min_samples` ? `DBScan` is very sensitive to these parameters. Even a small change in `eps` might change the behaviour of your model.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I ran it overnight and it was still running. So maybe 8 hours.

Comment: @Kalsi I meant that amount is just a single feature so my dataset was 1million by 1 matrix as compared to text which after converting to a tfidf matrix generated 100 feauters. so 1 million by 100 matrix.

Comment: Not directly an answer to the question, but the [open3d DBSCAN implementation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/Basic/pointcloud.html#DBSCAN-clustering) is about 2x faster than sklearn (34ms v 62ms on 10,000 points on my Intel i7)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your epsilon is too large.

If most points are within epsilon of most other points, then the runtime will be quadratic O(n²). So begin with *small* values!

You can't just add/remove features and leave epsilon unchanged.

Comment: Why would epsilon/point-density change the runtime complexity? The pairwise distances have to be calculated regardless.

Answer (score 1):

### Use more cores.

Use the `n_jobs` parameter. **Define it as: `n_jobs=-1`inside `DBSCAN` class.**

**Example:**

```
Y=data['amount'].values
Y=Y.reshape(-1,1)
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples= 10, algorithm='kd_tree', n_jobs=-1)
dbscan.fit_predict(Y)
labels = dbscan.labels_
print(labels.size)
clusters = labels.tolist()
#printing the value and its label
for a, b in zip(labels, Y):
    print(a, b)
```